# File Not Found Exception -webapp folder throwing exception when excuting from Jar

Tags: java, maven, netbeans

I have a maven project which run a web service. This is the path of my web app:

```
\src\main\resources\webapp\WEB-INF
```

When I run via the IDE, I get no errors. But I get this error when executing :

```
java -jar ServiceNowWS-1.0-jar-with-dependencies.jar
```

I created a server to run my web service :

```
server = new Server(9997);
WebAppContext webapp = new WebAppContext();
webapp.setContextPath("/");
webapp.setWar("src/main/webapp");
server.setHandler(webapp);
```

But it can not find my web.xml, so I have get response error : 404

Comment: you must have one folder like etc, do you have it?

Answer (score 1):

According to [maven standards](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-standard-directory-layout.html), the WEB-INF directory should be under \src\main\webapp and not \src\main\resources\webapp.  Maybe this plays a role?